How to capture output from .exe in PowerShell?
I have an application, app.exe, that outputs a list of commands when executed without any arguments.
I want to capture this output into a variable.
I have the lines:
$cmd = "X:\app.exe"
$output = cmd /c $cmd '2>&1'

However, output always returns as empty. When I run the line & $cmd directly, I can see the long list of commands returned.
<COMMANDS>
a: add file
d: delete file
u: update file
...

I have also tried the following, but still could not capture the output.
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.FileName = $cmd
$psi.Arguments = ''
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true

$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $psi
$process.Start() | Out-Null

$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$output += $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

I am unsure as to why the output is failing to be captured.
EDIT:
So it seems that I am unable to capture the output of any external process.
I tried replicating this behavior on another computer testing with various applications (python.exe, 7za.exe, etc.), but it all worked as expected and I was able to capture the output with just
$out = & $cmd


'2>&1' shouldn't be quoted

$output = cmd /c $cmd '2>&1' should work ('2>&1', due to being quoted, is passed to cmd /c and therefore a redirection interpreted by cmd.exe). Assuming that $cmd refers to an existing executable, you can also skip the use of cmd and use PowerShell's own redirections: [string[]] $output = & $cmd 2>&1. To ignore a nonexistent executable, use [string[]] $output = try { & $cmd 2>&1 } catch { }

@mklement0 It seems that the command $out = (python3 --version *>&1).ToString() doesn't work either and returns the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

@Alfyn: I cannot reproduce this behavior, except if a define a python3 command that produces no output, e.g. by defining the following function: function python3 { }

$output = X:\app.exe

Clear-Host
app.exe
Start-Sleep 01
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^a")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Get-Clipboard | Out-FIle C:\TEMP\AppExe-Output.txt

might work but is not as powershell...esk
Does this not work?
App.exe | Out-File C:\TEMP\App-OutFile.txt


Not only is it not PowerShell-idiomatic, like any GUI automation based on emulating user actions (sending keystrokes) it is inherently brittle and platform-specific (Windows), and, with your specific approach, additionally has side effects (clearing the console and its scrollback buffer).
